# If $P(T\mid X) = a$ and $P(T\mid Y) = b$, what is $P(T \mid X\cap Y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Is it possible to figure out $P(T\mid X\cap Y)$ if we know $P(T\mid X)$ and $P(T\mid Y)$?

Extra Information: $X$ and $Y$ are non-mutually exclusive while $Z$'s relationship with $X$ and $Y$ is arbitrary. The probability distributions are also arbitrary.

Comment: Welcome to Mathstackexchange! Could you provide the attempts you've made so far?

Comment: Thanks. I feel as if this is too little information to figure $P(T | X\cap Y)$ as there are way too many unknowns. Any attempt posted (if the calculation is possible) will be very incomplete.

Comment: Well, have you tried to show that the given information is too little? You could look for two examples of $P,T,X,Y$ where $P(T|X)$ and $P(T|Y)$ are the same in both examples while $P(T|X\cap Y)$ is different in the two examples.